# Tweaking MySQL configuration to support hundreds of connections locking the same table

Tags: mysql, design-patterns, pool

I have a resources table with 2000 rows. 
Engine is innodb. There is a 'free_at' field (indexed).
On each request I need to lock the table, get a free resource (ordered by 'free_at' column), update that row to non free, and release the lock.

This is a basic pool implementation that I've been using and had worked fine with 100-200 connections and less than 1000 rows (resources in the pool).

Right now there are about 800 processes that are constantly requesting resources from the table (each every 10-15 seconds, so the average is up to 80\s).

My bottle neck is the lock wait time, which is ranging between 30 to 60 seconds (!) for each request. I'm sure there is some configuration I should change to make it lock and release faster.

I've tried changing the engine type to MEMORY but that didn't improve the lock wait time.

Should I look for another pool solution that is not MySQL based and can dispense resources by priority (which in my case is the 'free_at' field)?

EDIT:

for locking I use
    `LOCK TABLES table_name WRITE`

Then selecting
    `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE (free_at < NOW() OR free_at is null) ORDER BY free_at ASC`

Updating the 'free_at' field
    `UPDATE table_name SET free_at = NOW() + INTERVAL 5 MINUTE WHERE id= 1234`

Finally unlocking
    `UNLOCK TABLES`

Table schema

```
`resources` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `free_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `free_at` (`free_at`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Comment: Can you show the table schema and SQL code you are using? Are you locking the whole table, or just a row using `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`?

Comment: The use of `free_at IS NULL` definitively defeats the use of an index in your `SELECT` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by internally buffering resources. Instead of fetching 1 resource at a time, I'm fetching 5 of them, thus reducing the amount of calls and locks on that table by a factor of 5.

Answer (score 0):

You need to lock rows in your table, not the whole table. Locking the whole table doesn't scale up, as you have discovered.

Stick with InnoDB.  The MEMORY and MyISAM access methods don't do this.

Assuming your `resource` table has the following columns (it can have others):

```
resource_id int not null primary key
free        int not null 1 means free, 0 means in use
free_at     timestamp not null
```

And assuming you want a transaction which will grab the oldest free resource row (`free` = 1), here's what you do from each client needing a resource.

```
 START TRANSACTION;

 SELECT resource_id
   FROM resource
  WHERE free = 1
  ORDER BY free_at ASC
  LIMIT 1
    FOR UPDATE;
```

At this point your application will get either a single resource_id, which is the one you can allocate, or it will get none. If it gets none, that means it has to wait and try again.

If you got a resource_id, update it to indicate it's in use.

```
 UPDATE resource
    SET free = 0,
        free_at = NOW()
  WHERE resource_id = 'the resource ID you just got';
```

Then, as soon as you can, do

```
 COMMIT;
```

to complete the transaction you started and release the lock on that row. This way of allocating resources works better than locking the table because each connection only needs to lock its own row.

If you *don't* get a resource id from the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` query, you need immediately to do

```
 ROLLBACK;
```

to cancel the transaction you started on that row. Then you need to wait and try again. Wait for a meaningful amount of time: at least the time it takes your application to use one of your resources and release it. If you wait a shorter amount of time, your many connections will hammer away on the resource table and slow things down.  If you need more resources, add some.

When your software is done with the resource it allocated, do this to release it back to the pool. You can just do this operation in auto-commit mode; there's no need for an explicit transaction here.  But do make sure your clients have autocommit mode turned on for this.

```
 UPDATE resource
    SET free = 1
  WHERE resource_id = 'the resource ID you have been using';
```

Please note; I don't understand exactly how you're using `free_at` so I may have that part of the logic wrong.

The `SELECT` operation finding the free resource will very likely be accelerated by adding a composite index, a *covering index*, on

```
 (free, free_at, resource_id)
```

Comment: I have tried using a SELECT FOR UPDATE before and have gotten dead lock exceptions. This is why I switched to entire row locking instead.

Comment: You've presented an XY problem: You want to do X, and you think Y is the best way of doing so. Instead of asking about X, you ask about Y.

Comment: I will definitely try again the proposed solution, just imagined there might be a best practice way to create a pool using entire table lock.

Comment: implementing this made the lock wait times longer. what happens when a row is locked (in transaction), and multiple other connections are trying to sort the table and get the next row? isn't that a problem?

Comment: Try skipping the ORDER BY and just doing the LIMIT 1. Make sure to commit the transaction as quickly as you can. Unless there's some reason you must cycle the resources, just grab the first eligible one. Make sure your searchable columns in your table are declared NOT NULL, and that you have eliminated `OR col IS NULL` from your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: for future reference, this solution did not solve the issue for me, and in fact adding an index actually decreased performance. I have accepted the answer as I'm sure it might be useful for other people in other scenarios.